# Label inside of \newtcbinputlisting giving incorrect ref number

Tags: cross-referencing, tcolorbox, ref, tcblisting, tcbinputlisting

In the code below, I am trying to reference some matlab code that is written using a `\newtcbinputlisting` environment.  When I attach a label to the code, the reference number come in as "1" or "a)" or some other different reference number instead of the desired "Matlab Algorithm 1.1".  Can you help me get the desired refernence number?  Thanks.

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}

\newcommand{\codeimg}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}}$}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm,
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{matlab}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=matlab,list inside=matlab,number within=chapter]{\inputmatlabold}[4][]{%
  enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
  fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\codeimg~#3},%
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Matlab Code~\thematlab~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small},list entry=#4,
  after upper={\centering\strut {\bfseries Matlab Code~\thematlab:}~#2},
  frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
  overlay={\draw[gray,line width=1mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},
  %
  listing file={#3},#1
}


\DeclareTCBInputListing[use counter=matlab,list inside=matlab,number within=chapter]{\inputmatlab}{O{}+m+O{#2}+m}{%
  enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
  fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\codeimg~#4},%
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Matlab Code~\thematlab~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small},list entry=#3,
  after upper={\centering\strut {\bfseries Matlab Code~\thematlab:}~#2},
  frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
  overlay={\draw[gray,line width=1mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},
  %
  listing file={#4},#1
}


\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
% create a file for output
!touch testFile.txt
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\matref}[1]{%
\hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{blue}{Matlab Algorithm \ref*{#1}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tcblistof{matlab}{List of codes}
\chapter{Some Code}
I am trying to reference the \matref{mat:code1} below

\inputmatlab{Expansion Algorithm\label{mat:code1}}[Other title]{sample.m}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbered `tcolorbox` environments use `label=...` option in order to access the cross-referencing features, so say `label=mat:code1` here in the optional argument of `\inputmatlab` instead `\label{mat:code1}` of the caption text, which will use the outer `\@currentlabel` content, which is set by the `\refstepcounter{chapter}` from `\chapter` macro.

(Of course, I do not recommend a numbered label name, i.e. `mat:code1` is no good style for labeling)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}

\newcommand{\codeimg}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}}$}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm,
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{matlab}



\DeclareTCBInputListing[use counter=matlab,list inside=matlab,number within=chapter]{\inputmatlab}{O{}+m+O{#2}+m}{%
  enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
  fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\codeimg~#4},%
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Matlab Code~\thematlab~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small},list entry=#3,
  after upper={\centering\strut {\bfseries Matlab Code~\thematlab:}~#2},
  frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
  overlay={\draw[gray,line width=1mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},
  %
  listing file={#4},#1
}


\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
% create a file for output
!touch testFile.txt
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\matref}[1]{%
\hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{blue}{Matlab Algorithm \ref*{#1}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tcblistof{matlab}{List of codes}
\chapter{Some Code}
I am trying to reference the \matref{mat:code1} below

\inputmatlab[label=mat:code1]{Expansion Algorithm}[Other title]{sample.m}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution, Dr. Hupfer.  I agree with your suggestion of not using a numbered label and will make the necessary changes.